# Find which is installed gcc or clang or both

Tags: node.js

I need to locate `gcc` or `clang`, whatever is installed, from my nodejs script. If both are installed I need to find both. How to do that?

In bash you usually just type `which gcc`. I know I can enumerate `process.env.PATH.split(':').map(......fs.stat()......)` but is there a easier builtin way?

Comment: You can invoke system commands like `which` from Node.js using the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) API.

Comment: Check [**command-exists**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-exists) module

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

function find_binaries(binaries) {
    var dirs = process.env.PATH.split(path.delimiter)
    var result = {}
    binaries.forEach(b=>result[b] = false)
    dirs.forEach(dir => {
        try {
            binaries.map(binary => {
                var f = dir + path.sep + binary
                var s = fs.statSync(f)
                result[binary] = true
            })
        }
        catch (e) {
            return
        }
    })
    return result
}

exports = find_binaries

console.log(find_binaries(['clang', 'gcc']))
```

returns:

```
{clang: true, gcc: false}
```